# Pre-conditions within @RequestMapping method?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I don't know how to redirect user if they do not meet certain preconditions for a @RequestMapping.

I have a simple form that after completion sends the user to "/secondForm" which is unrelated to "/firstForm", how can I restrict access to "/secondForm", if first form has not been completed?

What makes this more difficult for me there is a controller in the middle.

**firstForm** --- (*submit*)---> **emailController** ----(*redirect*)----> **secondForm**

Comment: You can perform a validation in your `html/jsp` page that validates all the fields before the post request is sent to the server.

Comment: @NicholasK how would that prevent someone accessing secondForm directly without completing firstForm?

Comment: So unless your validation on the `firstForm` is complete, control would not go to the `Controller`. If you implement this, all requests now coming to your controller are complete from the `firstForm`

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough on my question. The issue I am having is that someone may be accessing secondForm directly by accessing its requestmapping /secondForm. My first form has both client side and server side validation, however, this does not prevent someone just going lcoalhost/secondForm and jumping the flow

Comment: I guess you should reconsider the design (just my opinion). Interceptors would be a good option then. But there would still be challenges.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I wish I could redesign it, however, the form is a requirement for the process as it has to support some sort of data anonymisation,i.e., be separate from the first form.   However, you did give me an idea where I could create a session storage variable using JS when submitting firstForm which would be a requirement for secondForm's HTML/JSP.

Comment: As always, happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect a user to another page when certain conditions are met, you can use an interceptor. Example interceptor class:

```
@Component
public class RedirectInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    if (request.getRequestURI().contains("secondForm") && modelAndView.getModel().get("someBoolean") == false {
        try {
            response.sendRedirect("/firstForm");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, Exception e) {

}
}
```

And register it in configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
RedirectInterceptor redirectInterceptor;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(redirectInterceptor);
}
}
```

If you prefer xml configuration over java then you can alternatively use this in your spring config xml:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="redirectInterceptor" class="path.to.your.interceptor.RedirectInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Brilliant, without your help, I wouldn't even know where to start and you gave me the answer I was looking for. thank you so much.
Quick one, if you don't mind, when it comes to the config class - do I have to mention this in any of the .xmls?

Comment: + by implementing the mvcconfig class, does that mean that I will have to redeisgn most of my app?

Comment: You can use either java or xml configuration. Choose what is more convenient for you. I added an example xml section to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found an additional way:

Using FlashAttribute, by assigning before the redirect in emailController that sets a value.

In applicationController, by using an if statement if there isn't a FlashAttribute then redirect is called to the root of the application.